# Activate/Desactivate notifications in an app having different notifications type

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I was looking at different forums and tutorials but did not find anything that cover what I want to do. At the moment my notifications are working fine but I am trying to give the options to the user to receive them or not.

My server is sending 3 kind of different notification, they are all messages:

1. You have a new message
2. A new user just connected
3. A user is very close to you

I have an option menu where I am giving the user the option to choose which notifications he wants to receive. He can select the combination he wants.

The problem I have is I do not know how to allow the app to display say the message 1 and 2, but not the 3, if that was the user choice. So far the solution I have is either showing 1, 2 and 3) or showing nothing. I have nothing in the middle.

Did anyone came across this and how did you solved it?
PS: This is for apple push notifications

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution, just combine silent notification with local notification

1) receive the silent notification

2) do the treatment base on the notification

3) send a local notification (or not) to create the desired effect